# On read shared preferences , only one object received

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, sharedpreferences, android-ondestroy

I'm trying to save some `Array` of objects to `SharedPreferences`.

How it's working on my app:

I have `RecyclerView` that contains clickable items. On click on these items, they are added to a new Array.
And the new array is shown in another view.
I'm trying to add the array to the `SharedPreferences` on `onDestroyView()` of fragment.
This means that when I kill the fragment, the array will be saved in `SharedPreferences`.

For now with my code, on read data I'm getting only the last object from the array, instead of all objects.

Here is my code:

```
private LightsHistory lightsHistory;
    private ArrayList<LightsHistory> lightHistories = new ArrayList<>();
```

Add item to another view:

```
public void addItemToHistory(int position) {
        String title = mLightsArray.get(position).getLampTitle();
        String desc = mLightsArray.get(position).getLampDesc();
        String imageURL = mLightsArray.get(position).getLampImageUrl();

        lightsHistory = new LightsHistory(imageURL, title, desc);
        lightHistories.clear();
        lightHistories.add(lightsHistory);

        for (int j = 0; j < lightHistories.size(); j++) {
            if (i == 3) {
                i = 0;
            }
            Glide.with(getContext())
                    .load(lightHistories.get(j).getmLightsIMG())
                    .override(150)
                    .into(historyItemsPH.get(i));
            i++;
        }


        saveToSharedPrefs(lightHistories);
    }
```

Save to SP

```
public void saveToSharedPrefs(ArrayList<LightsHistory> lightHistories) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        String json = gson.toJson(lightHistories);

        editor.putString(TAG, json);
        editor.commit();
        Log.d(TAG, "saveToSharedPrefs: "+json);
    }
```

Read from SP

```
public void readFromSharedPrefs() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = sharedPrefs.getString(TAG, "");
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<LightsHistory>>() {
        }.getType();
        ArrayList<LightsHistory> arrayList = gson.fromJson(json, type);
        if (arrayList != null) {
            for (int j = 0; j < lightHistories.size(); j++) {
                Log.d(TAG, "readFromSharedPrefs: " + arrayList.get(j).getmLightsTitle()
                        + "\n" + arrayList.get(j).getmLightsDesc()
                        + "\n" + arrayList.get(j).getmLightsIMG());
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lightsHistory = new LightsHistory(imageURL, title, desc);
lightHistories.clear();
lightHistories.add(lightsHistory);
```

You are calling `list.clear()` and adding one element to it so the list will have only one element when it's saved to the shared preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Remove "lightHistories.clear();"
If you want to clear arraylist, put It after you use method saveToSharedPrefs().

Regards.